# Maximum Attachment size

Tags: apex, attachment, visual

I am passing some data as string from my Visualforce page to apex via apex function, I store that data by in attachment body through apex code. What is the maximum size of data that I can store in Attachment body via apex?

Will this have the same 2gb limit for Salesforce lightning as mentioned in documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Because of the Heap Size limit, you will be limited to 6MB of data, 4.5MB if you have to base-64 encode the data. If you need larger file sizes, call the [Chatter API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/features_files.htm) directly by way of JavaScript.

Comment: And if you are using VF page, you can utilize JSForce library to post any sizes of attachments (which are up to 25 mbs)

Comment: I see, I am assuming heap size limit of 6MB will be a consideration when passing data from VF to apex of same size, but in my case I have to store one message at a time and then append to same file when next message arrives, would I be able to utilize all storage limit by following this saving data in a  step by step approach? If yes, then limit would be 25 MB?

Comment: @Badar The maximum string length is the same as the maximum heap size, so you will be limited to 6MB (technically 6,000,000 Unicode characters) before you will reach a hard limit. If you need more, consider using direct API calls, such as by using apex:remoteObjects or the REST API.